# Why when loading the saved text file into list-box of tkinter (python) displays every saved data input into one line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

```
from tkinter import*
import webbrowser

def add():
    name = entry1.get()
    id = entry2.get()
    listbox.insert(END, name+ " : " +id)

def delete():
    select = listbox.curselection()
    index = select[0]
    Listbox.delete(index)

def save():
    list1 = list(listbox.get(0,END))
    f = open("file.txt","w")
    f.writelines(str(list1))
    f.close()

read = open("file.txt","r")
data_list = read.readlines()
read.close()
data_list = [data.rstrip() for data in data_list]

win = Tk()
win.title("Class")

frame1=Frame(win)
frame2=Frame(win)
frame1.pack()
frame2.pack()

label1 = Label(frame1,text="Name : ")
label1.grid(row=0,column=0)
label2 = Label(frame1,text="Id : ")
label2.grid(row=1,column=0)

name = StringVar()
entry1 = Entry(frame1,textvariable=name)
entry1.grid(row=0,column=1)

id = StringVar()
entry2 = Entry(frame1,textvariable=id)
entry2.grid(row=1,column=1)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame2,orient=VERTICAL)

listbox = Listbox(frame2,selectmode=EXTENDED,yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set,width=60)
listbox.pack()

scrollbar.config(command=listbox)

for item in data_list:
    listbox.insert(END,item)

button1 = Button(frame2,text="Add",command=add)
button1.pack()

button2 = Button(frame2,text="Delete",command=delete)
button2.pack()

button3 = Button(frame2,text="Save to File",command=save)
button3.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

**[Please open and see the below uploaded screenshots for better understanding of the question]**
 
**While performing the application first time**
[Screenshot of opening application for 1st time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiM9I.png) 
1. Adding "Mike : 11" and "Bob : 22". Here both are in **separate lines** . 
2. Saving the file and closing the application.

**While restarting the application**
[Screenshot of opening application for 2nd time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGH1m.png)
1. Why does the data of Mike and Bob came into same like and how can I make this thing load in separate lines 
(exactly like: 
        Mike : 11 
        Bob : 22 
)

Comment: If you inspect the saved text file, you will find that you have saved the content in one line due to the line `f.writelines(str(list1))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. Change the way you put the file data in the `Listbox`.
2. Change the way you save them to the file.

For the first solution,because you save a string with list format.While you read this saved file,the string will be:

[image]

You need to change the string to list.An easy way:

```
import ast

....

read = open("file.txt","r")
data_list = ast.literal_eval(read.read())
read.close()
```

Or use some string-processing operation.That's a little complex.

For the second solution,just change the way you save it.add a `\n` in each line.(Because you use `.readlines()` to read the file.)

```
def save():
    with open("file.txt","w") as f:
        for i in listbox.get(0,END):
            f.write(i+"\n")
```

Comment: It worked perfectly!! Thank you. But I have another problem coming - which is - now the data of Mike and Bob are saved but when I open the application and select "Mike" or "Bob", and try to delete that entry, it is showing me an error. Like : Listbox.delete(index)
TypeError: delete() missing 1 required positional argument: 'first' . How do I fix this? Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: @TejasDhanani ...You used `Listbox.delete(index)` which should be `listbox.delete(index)` because your `Listbox` widget is variable `listbox`.`Listbox` is a class.